# Append string to specific div only once if same div is used throughout DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

I'm working on building a portfolio site and I'm pulling content from a JSON file. It's working, but I'm having a hard time generating the content only one time. I'm creating a `div` with the project type's name, and then adding `container` and `row` inside to make it work with Bootstrap. Then, I'm going through the projects and pulling the data, and creating a new `div` inside `row` that's called `port-card`, and `port-card` will contain the data. It's working, but in my for loop I'm using jQuery's append and it's appending the data to EVERY single row, which means I'm adding the data twice (or however many rows there currently are) instead of just one time.

EDIT: Thanks to T.J. Crowder, I tried using `.eq(n)` and I've added a runnable snippet below. Now I'm trying to figure out how to keep the generated data in the first `wordpress-plugins` div rather than having the second iteration of the for loop add it to the second `div`.

```js
 var catList = ["WordPress Plugins", "Websites"];
 var categories = [{cat: "WordPress Plugins", title: "Price Quote Plugin"}, {cat: "WordPress Plugins", title: "House Plan Search"}];
 
 for (var i = 0; i < catList.length; i++) {
    temp = catList[i];
    temp = temp.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); 
    $('.projects').append('<div class="' + temp + '"><div class="container"><div class="row"></div></div></div>');
  }

  if ($('.wordpress-plugins')[0]) {
    var rows = $(".row");
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
        var catNameTemp = categories[i].cat;
        var projectTitle = categories[i].title;
        if(catNameTemp == "WordPress Plugins"){
          rows.eq(i).append('<div class="port-card"><h3>' + projectTitle + '</h3></div>');
       }
    }
  }
```

```css
.projects {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.port-card {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
}

h3 {
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="projects">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.row')` will create a jQuery set with all elements with class `row` in it. If you want to access just a single element in that set, you can use [`.eq(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to do so (`n` = the index, starting with 0).

So for instance, if you have as many rows as categories, you might do:

```
var rows = $(".row");
```

...before the loop, then `rows.eq(i).append(...)` within the loop.

---

Looking at the runnable snippet you added, you don't have a row-per-category, so the above wouldn't apply. See comments in the snippet:

```js
var catList = ["WordPress Plugins", "Websites"];
var categories = [
  {cat: "WordPress Plugins", title: "Price Quote Plugin"},
  {cat: "WordPress Plugins", title: "House Plan Search"},
  // Added this to show putting things in other category lists
  {cat: "Websites", title: "Some Website"}
];
// A map of category names to the divs that represent them
var catDivs = Object.create(null);

// Look up the projects div once and reuse it
var projects = $(".projects");
for (var i = 0; i < catList.length; i++) {
  var catName = catList[i];
  var clsName = catName.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  // Create and add the category div, remember it in the map
  catDivs[catName] = $('<div class="' + clsName + '"><div class="container"><div class="row"></div></div></div>').appendTo(projects);
}
// Done with this
projects = null;

// Add categories to their container
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
  var catDiv = catDivs[categories[i].cat];
  if (catDiv) {
    var projectTitle = categories[i].title;
    catDiv.find(".row").append('<div class="port-card"><h3>' + projectTitle + '</h3></div>');
  }
}
```

```css
.projects {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.port-card {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="projects">
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be a really good answer too, but it didn't quite get me the results I was looking for. When I tried this, it added the second set of data to the next category `div` outside of the first div I was trying to work with. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Coltvant - It's hard to say without knowing your HTML structure. It would appear you don't have a category = row relationship. It looks like maybe each catList entry = row, so you may have to use the `.eq` tool differently than above. I certainly would **not** add a unique ID to every row, that gets unmanageable quickly.

Comment: @Coltvant - The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Instead, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: I added a runnable snippet with my code and edited my question.

Comment: @Coltvant - Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique Id on the row that you want to append data in and then append data in that row only. Like shown below

```
for (var i = 0; i < catList.length; i++) {
 temp = catList[i];
 temp = temp.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); //convert string to lower case and make spaces dashes to create class names
 $('.projects').append('<div class="' + temp + '"><div class="container"><div class="row" id="uniqueId"></div></div></div>');
 }

if ($('.wordpress-plugins')[0]) {
 for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
    var catNameTemp = categories[i].cat;
    var projectTitle = categories[i].title;
     if(catNameTemp == "WordPress Plugins"){
      $('#uniqueId').append('<div class="port-card"><h3>' + projectTitle + '</h3></div>');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code `$('.row').append('<div class="port-card"><h3>' + projectTitle + '</h3></div>');` notice how you wrote `$('.row').append(`.

This makes jQuery append your new div to the every instance of the *class* of "row".

What you need to do is be more specific about which row you want your new div to be appended to.